# Jstree issue- executes only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a simple js page and a html page: I want to get a jstree structure when i click on the button. I am getting the structure on the first click.. However When i click once more it gives me a normal structure.. Is this a jstree bug... Please help

Html code:

```
<body><button id="idClickMe">Click me</button><div id='jstree'></div></body>
```

Js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#idClickMe').click(function(){ 
        var resultant="<ul><li data-jstree='{'selected' : true, 'opened' : true }><span>Friend</span><ul><li>abc</li></ul></li><li><span>Wife</span></li><li><span>Company</span></li></ul>";
        $("#jstree").html(resultant);
        $("#jstree").jstree(); 
        //$("#jstree").jstree("refresh");
    }); 
});
```

Comment: The 1st code is html and second is my js page

Answer (score 1):

You need to destroy the tree before HTML change and recall.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/osnam3bz/1/)**

```
$('#idClickMe').on('click',function () {
    var resultant = "<ul><li data-jstree='{'selected' : true, 'opened' : true }><span>Friend</span><ul><li>abc</li></ul></li><li><span>Wife</span></li><li><span>Company</span></li></ul>";
    $("#jstree").jstree('destroy').html(resultant);
    $("#jstree").jstree();
});
```

Comment: Hi Rejith,Cant believe the answer was so simple.. Tried for days... It works!!!!!! thanks

Comment: Also if anyone can help me with this... Is there a way to configure the jstree structure. The  pane where my tree is getting populated is of less width and so the whole structure cannot be seen. I have used a scroll bar for the same to view the whole structure. However If i could configure the structure and make it more vertical I can save on some width space. Also if I replace the icons by smaller icons, it might help. Any help??

Comment: @ParthaKalita, if this answer helped to resolve your issue, please mark it as accepted using the green V mark on the left under the votes.

Comment: @ParthaKalita Can you add the comment as a question with more details, then someone might be able to help. There is a chance that no one notice the comments.